# Multi-processing Pool has a map() function - is there a similar way to apply multiprocessing to reduce()?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have 3 lists of different character frequencies as they appear in text. I create a Pool of processes to execute the task of applying an equation to each entry in those lists, and returning the new lists. Something like:

```
ans1 = list((pool.map(single_entropy, lst1)))
ans2 = list((pool.map(double_entropy, lst2)))
ans3 = list((pool.map(triple_entropy, lst3)))
```

However, to actually create lst1, lst2, and lst3, I use the functools.reduce() function, like so:

```
char_freq = {}

def getcharfreq(char_freq, ch):
    char_freq[ch] = char_freq.get(ch, 0) + 1
    return char_freq

# Get the frequencies of each character in the text
functools.reduce(getcharfreq, text, char_freq)

lst = list(char_freq.values())
return lst
```

to get the character frequencies in the text. Is there a way to apply multi-processing to my reduce function, sort of like I am able to do above with Pool? Most of my processing time comes from finding the character frequencies, so that's where I'm trying to see if this can improve performance.

Comment: `reduce` works by serially appying the function to the intermediate results. Mulitprocessing and mulithreading process things in _parallel_ — so the answer is "no".

Comment: @martineau I thought so, thanks!